# How to get image's (jpeg, raw) capture date time with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, exif, capture

By now, I can only get image file creation date which is several seconds later than capture date. How can I get image's capture date from Exif?

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        set the source_folder to (folder of the front window) as text
    on error -- no open folder windows

        set the source_folder to (path to desktop folder) as text

    end try
    set these_items to the selection
end tell

set repeatCount to 1
repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items

    set this_item to (item i of these_items) as alias
    set this_info to info for this_item
    set {file_name, file_ext} to splitExtension from the name of this_info
    set capture_date to (the creation date of this_info)

    set formatted_date to (my dateFormat(capture_date))
    set new_name to formatted_date & file_ext
    -- check to see if it's already there
    tell application "Finder"
        if (exists item (source_folder & new_name)) then
            --- display dialog new_name & " already exists."
            set new_name to formatted_date & "_" & repeatCount & file_ext
            set name of this_item to new_name
            set repeatCount to 1 + repeatCount
        else
            set name of this_item to new_name
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the EXIF data with help from AppleScriptObjC and AppKit.

The result is an Applescript record containing the data, the capture date is probably the value for key `DateTimeDigitized` which is a string.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions
use framework "AppKit"

set theFile to (choose file)

set imageRep to current application's NSBitmapImageRep's imageRepWithContentsOfFile:(POSIX path of theFile)
set exifData to imageRep's valueForProperty:(current application's NSImageEXIFData)
if exifData is missing value then
    display dialog "No EXIF data found" buttons "Cancel" default button 1
else
    set exifData to exifData as record
    set captureDate to DateTimeDigitized of exifData
end if
```

Comment: There's also `DateTimeOriginal`, which might be the same as `DateTimeDigitized`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks. It works but the date format is something like this: 2018/08/17 13/12/04.JPG, how to get rid of the slash? Can I define the date format before getting it?

Comment: @vadian Ooooh, the slash should be ":" which is allowed in file name, Mac shows it as "/" automatically. By now I replace it with `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the "/"`